# How can I identify Grammatical Categories in a sentence?

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics, grammar

Please excuse the fact that I'm not an academically trained Linguist.

I am working on a computer program with example sentences and their equivalents in different languages.

The idea I am trying to explore is that by compiling a list of example English sentences that encapsulate common speech patterns, 
having a native of another language add their language equivalents will give us a list of foreign sentences that encapsulate the same meta-grammar concepts.

For example:

**English <-> Turkish**

grammatical categories: present tense.

- Joe is coming <=> Joe geliyor

grammatical categories: present tense, with.

- I'm walking with her  <=> Onunla yürüyorum

grammatical categories: present tense, with, together.

- I am doing it together with Kayla <=> Kayla'yla beraber yapıyoruz

grammatical categories: present tense, interrogative.

- Are you running?  <=> Koşuyor musun?

I've been using  https://glossary.sil.org/term/grammatical-category as a reference, but it's not quite what I'm after.

I'm getting stumped very easily. For example, I don't know what to call the grammatical categories appearing in these sentences:

- Ders çalışmak zor <=>  It is hard to study
- Bulmak kolay  <=>  It is easy to find
- Gitmek zor  It is hard to go

My questions are as follows:

1. What I naively refer to as grammatical categories, am I using the
   right term, or is there a more suitable academically recognised
   title for such an idea?
2. Can you suggest any tips or ideas on how I
   can identify the grammatical categories in a sentence pattern?

Comment: 1. Yes, you're doing fine. 2. No, it's your theory, so make up whatever categories seem to work best.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, and a difficult one, too.

It is difficult, because languages differ in the grammatical categories that are obligatorily expressed, and they differ in how the categories are exactly defined. For a cross-linguistic approach, I suggest reading something about [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.github.io), a currently hot proposal for unified tags across different languages.

When you have digested that, you can probably come up with more specific questions.

Comment: Very interesting! I've been reading through pages on Universal Dependency. How does it relatre/compare to [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage
), are they competing schools of thought?

Comment: No relation at all, Universal Dependencies deals with grammatical categories, Natural Semantic Metalanguage deals with semantics, so the two things have different domains.